# How to convert int number into time - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, I have a time format: 1000

how do I convert into MySQL Time() 10:00:00

It can also be more complex, since some numbers are 3 digits long, for example: 
900 into MySQL Time() 09:00:00

Let me know if this needs more explaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CONVERT()  -- (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-convert.html)

You'll have to pad it with zeros to show CONVERT() that it is in hours and not minutes.

**Specific to your example:**

```
> SELECT CONVERT(CONCAT('1000','00'), TIME) AS time1;
time1
10:00:00
```

or

```
> SELECT CONVERT(CONCAT(`fieldname`,'00'), TIME) AS time1 FROM `tablename`;
time1
10:00:00
```

Comment: Great thank you! now how do I now insert the value into the correct row with the Datatype Time()? Sorry I didn't make that clear in my question.

Answer (score 2):

You just want to use [str_to_date()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

cast your into to a char so its a string and pad it with lpad to keep a leading 0 :)

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(LPAD(CAST(my_col AS CHAR(25)), 4, '0'), '%H') -- or %k
```

or you can just drop the cast since mysql will do the converting for you

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(LPAD(my_col, 4, '0'), '%k')
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c07c/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select cast(number*100 as time)
```

Explanation: as mysql documentation on [time data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html) says:

> MySQL interprets abbreviated values without colons using the assumption that the two rightmost digits represent seconds (that is, as elapsed time rather than as time of day). For example, you might think of '1112' and 1112 as meaning '11:12:00' (12 minutes after 11 o'clock), but MySQL interprets them as '00:11:12' (11 minutes, 12 seconds). Similarly, '12' and 12 are interpreted as '00:00:12'.

So, if you want to interpret 1000 as 10 hours and 0 minutes, you need to multiply your number by 100 an interpret it as a time expression.